# Remove an associative array by key from finding a value in that array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing associative array of multiple arrays. I then have an array of "names" that I need to find per each in this previous array and remove that array by key. The goal here is to take an existing array of documents, allow user to "delete" them, so I have to compare the names of the files user wants to delete, and then unset each of those arrays in my parent array, and then pass this final array into the database to be saved as the user's "updated" list.

Psudeo code would be:
- Compare `$names` array for each name, look in `$parentArray` to find its key where `name` matches the name in the `$names` array. Inside this `foreach`, unset array.

My associative array of multiple arrays is here:

```
Array
(
[0] => PetManagement\\Pet\\Document Object
(
[file:protected] => https://url.com/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
[name:protected] => file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
[fileType:protected] => audio/mp3
[timestamp:protected] => 2019-08-21 08:28:12
[authorID:protected] => 2
[extension:protected] =>
[extensionIcon:protected] =>
)

[1] => PetManagement\\Pet\\Document Object
(
[file:protected] => https://url.com/file-sample_100kB.docx
[name:protected] => file-sample_100kB.docx
[fileType:protected] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
[timestamp:protected] => 2019-08-21 08:28:12
[authorID:protected] => 2
[extension:protected] =>
[extensionIcon:protected] =>
)

[2] => PetManagement\\Pet\\Document Object
(
[file:protected] => https://url.com/file-sample_100kB.odt
[name:protected] => file-sample_34343kB.odt
[fileType:protected] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
[timestamp:protected] => 2019-08-21 08:28:12
[authorID:protected] => 2
[extension:protected] =>
[extensionIcon:protected] =>
)

[3] => PetManagement\\Pet\\Document Object
(
[file:protected] => https://url.com/file-sample_100kB.odt
[name:protected] => file-sample_100kB.odt
[fileType:protected] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
[timestamp:protected] => 2019-08-21 08:29:01
[authorID:protected] => 2
[extension:protected] =>
[extensionIcon:protected] =>
)

)
```

I pass in an array of "names" like `['file-sample_100kB.odt','file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3']`, and I want to search this large array to remove the keys that have the `name` key match each value in this array, and `unset` the key.

So in my example, using the `$names` array, I would be removing key `3` and  `0`.

The general code I have been using is below, but I can't seem to get this to work correctly:

```
$docs = $p->getDocuments(); //existing $parentArray
$docsToRemove = explode(',',$this->postData['documents']); //create array of names we want to remove from $docs

foreach ($docsToRemove as $key=>$value) {
    //$value is the name we want to remove
    //'name' is the assoc array key we want to remove
    error_log(print_r(array_search($value, array_column($docs, 'name'))),true); //returns empty array
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Prior to this, I was doing multiple `foreach` loops, but was told simply using a mix of `array_search()` and `array_column()` would be a better more advanced solution.

Comment: That's not an associative array of multiple arrays that's a normal array of objects. All the properties you shared are protected so the only way to access them is if those objects implement a getter for those properties

Comment: `array_filter` + getter for `name` property, `getName()` I presume.

Comment: each value (name, timestamp, etc) does have a getter/setter in the Class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Filter your array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a callback like this:

```
$docsToRemove = explode(',',$this->postData['documents']); //create array of names we want to remove from $docs

$filtered = array_filter(
    $docs,
    function ($doc) use ($docsToRemove) { return !in_array($doc->getName(), $docsToRemove); }
);
```

Comment: your solution is working. i wasn't getting the rudimentary point that to get the `name` would require a Getter. would you be able to explain what your `$filtered` var is doing line by line?